# Boundary Value Analysis, Why does use two values inside the boundary?

Tags: testing

I can't understand why to use two values inside the boundary when using Boundary Value Analysis.
For instance, the program has the requirement: 1) Values between 1 and 100 are true, otherwise false.

```
func calc(x):
  if (x >= 1 and x <= 100):
    return True
  else:
    return False
```

A lot of books (Pressman, for instance) say you have to use the inputs 0, 1, 2, 99, 100 and 101 to test such program.

So, my question is: Why does use the inputs '2' and '99'?
I try to make a program with a fault that the test case set (0, 1, 2, 99, 100 and 101) expose a fail and the test case set (0, 1, 100, 101) does not expose it. 
I can't make such program.

Could you make such program? 
If not, it is a waste of resource create redundant test cases '2' and '99'.

Answer (score 0):

The basic requirement is to have +-1 of the boundary values. So to test values for a range of 1-100

1. One test case for exact boundary values of input domains each means
   1 and 100.
2. One test case for just below boundary value of input domains each
   means 0 and 99.
3. One test case for just above boundary values of input domains each
   means 2 and 101.

To answer your question - Why does use the inputs '2' and '99'? It is because if you are following BVA, you are checking both the limits (upper as well as lower) of the range to ensure that the software is behaving correctly. However, there are no hard and fast rules. If the range is big enough, then you should have more test points. You can also test the middle values as part of BVA.

Also, you can use Switch Case statements to create a program or multiple Ifs.

Comment: Yeah. But I would like to know Why. In your example, I think the values 1 and 99 is redundant. Try to make a program that test cases (0, 100, -1, 99, 1 and 101) finds a bug and the test cases (0, 100, -1, 101) does not find it.

Comment: As I said, BVA is defined like that but there is no hard and fast rule. It all depends if you want to follow a business practise or not. The idea of BVA is to ensure that boundaries are correct as it is one of the most vulnerable entry/exit point in an application.